# Relative layout inside drawer layout: relative layout params cannot be cast into drawer layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to use a relative layout inside a drawer so that I can include a list view and a grid view. Receiving the following error while running:

Logcat Error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <!-- ListView to display slider menu -->
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_relative_layout"
        >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"      
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"         
     />
       <GridView
        android:id="@+id/images_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"      
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
         />
   </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: post the full error stack trace

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this ??

Answer (score 1):

Please check your java code. Make sure you're using the right layout parameters. You might be referring to layouts other than your drawer layout.

Might happen here:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Or here:

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just complete POC running give it a try ,
here is the layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view.
-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivwLogo"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/medicinecarticon" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/jji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivwLogo"
            android:text="huhuuhul" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For main activity please download complete code base
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1gIYJI3B4FWDE0bGpMZnhGQmc/view?usp=sharing
Uploaded complete project hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

You're using :

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_relative_layout);
```

The DrawerLayout is always inflated from the `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` view and not from the layout that you're including in the drawer.

Comment: I have used drawer_layout in my main activity.